# Filter mysql results based on checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to filter mysql results based on checkboxes that have been ticked. My query works on the first check but returns nothing on the second filter. My checkbox array is $_POST['country'] which I implode in the GetSQLValueString function to create the comma separated values - (United Kingdom, France) etc. I am using the MySQL IN clause for the multiple selections.

I need it to filter multiple country selections

```
if (isset($_POST['country_submit']) && $_POST['country'] != '') {   
    mysql_select_db($database_tub, $tub);
    $query_trade = sprintf("
SELECT u.user_id,
       u.contact_person,
       u.company,
       u.country,
       u.pic_small,
       u.website,
       SUM(u.trader_or_bond = %s
           AND t.user_id IS NOT NULL) AS count
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN trading t ON u.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE u.trader_or_bond = %s AND u.country IN(%s)
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(t.user_id) DESC", 
GetSQLValueString('trader', "text"), 
GetSQLValueString('trader', "text"),
GetSQLValueString(implode(',', $_POST['country']), "text"));
    $trade = mysql_query($query_trade, $tub) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Is $_POST['country'] an array of (not numeric) strings ? If so, `u.country IN(%s)` would become `u.country IN(United Kingdom, France)` and that's an error in SQL. The correct form would be `u.country IN("United Kingdom", "France")` (escaped by ").

Comment: I can get it to work by surrounding countries with single quotes like  $SingleQuotes = "'".implode("','", $_POST['country'])."'"; I have to put this directly into the IN($SingleQuotes) clause so its not going through the GetSQLValueString function - how do I make it safe first?

Comment: can you provide a quick example so I can see what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this but not sure if safe for MySQL injection plus its not as clean as I would like.

```
if (isset($_POST['country_submit']) && $_POST['country'] != '') {   

$SingleQuotes = "'".implode("', '", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['country']))."'";
    mysql_select_db($database_tub, $tub);
    $query_trade = sprintf("
SELECT u.user_id,
       u.contact_person,
       u.company,
       u.country,
       u.pic_small,
       u.website,
       SUM(u.trader_or_bond = %s
           AND t.user_id IS NOT NULL) AS count
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN trading t ON u.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE u.trader_or_bond = %s AND u.country IN($SingleQuotes)
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(t.user_id) DESC", 
GetSQLValueString('trader', "text"), 
GetSQLValueString('trader', "text"));
$trade = mysql_query($query_trade, $tub) or die(mysql_error());
}
```